# I use watchEffect to monitor computed changes, the computed value of compted does not change, but watchEffect is still executed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I use watchEffect to monitor computed changes, the computed value of compted does not change, but watchEffect is still executed.

```js
const a = ref({ val: 1 });

const b = computed(() => a.value.val);

watchEffect(() => {
  console.log('watchEffect', b.value);
});

watch(b, () => {
  console.log('watch', b.value);
});

function handleClick() {
  a.value = { val: 2 };
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's called because `value` is changed. How can Vue reactivity 'know' that you need a.value.val and not a.value? Use regular watch for more precise ops

Answer (score 0):

This behavior occurs because watchEffect run on init, regardless if your variable changes or not